How do you structure your test cases in a folder system for Automation Testing?
Let's say you have a simple todo list application with login feature and a sidebar with calendar. You are using Playwright or Cypress or similar.
Does your folder structure look like this?

src


tests






e2e










positive












negative










regression










positive












negative










smoke










positive












negative







or what kind of folder structure do you use?
Also,how do you name your test cases? Do you have any naming convention, camel case etc...
